# Timestamp '"2013-08-19 09:50:37.000"' is not recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

In snowflake I am trying to do the following command:

```
copy into trips from @citibike_trips
file_format=CSV;
```

Before this command, I have already created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "CITIBIKE"."PUBLIC"."TRIPS" 
    ("TRIPDURATION" INTEGER
      , "STARTTIME" TIMESTAMP
      , "STOPTIME" TIMESTAMP
      , "START_STATION_ID" INTEGER
      , "START_STATION_NAME" STRING
      , "START_STATION_LATITUDE" FLOAT
      , "START_STATION_LONGITUDE" FLOAT
      , "END_STATION_ID" INTEGER
      , "END_STATION_NAME" STRING
      , "END_STATION_LATTITUDE" FLOAT
      , "END_STATION_LONGITUDE" FLOAT
      , "BIKEID" INTEGER
      , "MEMBERSHIP_TYPE" STRING
      , "USERTYPE" STRING
      , "BIRTH_YEAR" INTEGER
      , "GENDER" INTEGER);
```

Now by typing the command copy into trips from @citibike_trips
file_format=CSV;

I am receiving the error: Timestamp '"2013-08-19 09:50:37.000"' is not recognized

I have already tried the solution, which I found on the Internet, which would be:

```
ALTER citibike SET  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT  = 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS';
```

But this is not helping. It is also not helping, if I try to use 'yyyy/mm/dd' or 'AUTO'

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your timestamp format has "-" not "/" as date separators.  Have you tried 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF' as your format?

Comment: Or, `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3` to capture those decimal seconds. [see here in the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#examples-of-using-date-and-time-formats) (and the section just above).

Comment: i have now also tried YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3, but this doesnt work as well. The error is still there ones i run the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message very closely, especially the highlighted parts:

> Timestamp '`"`2013-08-19 09:50:37.000`"`' is not recognized

Your timestamp format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3` is correct, but the string includes double quotes. You can specify `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'` in your file format to correct this.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution. i have recreated the file format and now that error disappeared. :)